# How to retrieve all time zones for Australia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

```
Rails version 5.2.rc1
```

I am trying to get all the timezones for Australia with  following

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('AU')`

but this returns only following Melbourne not listing at all

```
    <select class="select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Adelaide">Adelaide</option>
    <option value="Antarctica/Macquarie">Antarctica/Macquarie</option>
    <option value="Australia/Broken_Hill">Australia/Broken_Hill</option>
    <option value="Australia/Currie">Australia/Currie</option>
    <option value="Australia/Eucla">Australia/Eucla</option>
    <option value="Australia/Lindeman">Australia/Lindeman</option>
    <option value="Australia/Lord_Howe">Australia/Lord_Howe</option>
    <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="Canberra">Canberra</option>
    <option value="Darwin">Darwin</option>
    <option value="Hobart">Hobart</option>
    <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
    <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>

</select>
```

I would ideally like if I can say with all the relevant AU zones. But I could not find a way. Any help pointers would be appreciated.

```
"Australian Eastern Standard Time (e.g. Sydney)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little bit complicated but I will try to do my best to explain that.

When you are calling `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('AU')` it executes `ActiveSupport::TimeZone#load_country_zones` ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L267)).

`load_country_zones`:
1) iterates over `TZInfo::Country.get(code).zone_identifiers`
2) maps zone identifiers using [`MAPPING` hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L32).

The second point is crucial, because here the Melbourne is lost.

The response of `TZInfo::Countru.get('AU').zone_identifiers` is:

```
[
 "Australia/Lord_Howe",
 "Antarctica/Macquarie",
 "Australia/Hobart",
 "Australia/Currie",
 "Australia/Melbourne",
 "Australia/Sydney",
 "Australia/Broken_Hill",
 "Australia/Brisbane",
 "Australia/Lindeman",
 "Australia/Adelaide",
 "Australia/Darwin",
 "Australia/Perth",
 "Australia/Eucla"
]
```

`Australia/Melbourne` is there. But then, when take a look at the `MAPPING` hash, you will see, that two keys has the same value - [`Australia/Melbourne`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L163).

```
"Canberra" => "Australia/Melbourne"
"Melbourne" => "Australia/Melbourne"
```

So, when ActiveSupport fetches the key for `Australia/Melbourne` by calling:

```
self[MAPPING.key('Australia/Melbourne')]
```

It gets back `Canberra` instead of `Melbourne` ([first matched key](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-key)).

To sum up - there is no `Melbourne` but there is a time zone used in `Melbourne`. It is just named differently.